# ArrayList method for list with sub categories

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot moviecatlog: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Actors =  (String) moviecatlog.child("Actors").getValue();
                Description = (String) moviecatlog.child("Description").getValue();
                Director = (String) moviecatlog.child("Director").getValue();
                Genre = (String) moviecatlog.child("Genre").getValue();
                Published = (String) moviecatlog.child("Published").getValue();
                MovieUrl = (String) moviecatlog.child("MovieUrl").getValue();
                Status = (String) moviecatlog.child("Status").getValue();
                ThumbUrl = (String) moviecatlog.child("ThumbUrl").getValue();
                Title = (String) moviecatlog.child("Title").getValue();
                id = (String) moviecatlog.child("id").getValue();


//                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(moviecatlog));

                ar = new ArrayList<String>();

                ar.add(Actors);
                ar.add(Description);
                ar.add(Director);
                ar.add(Genre);
                ar.add(MovieUrl);
                ar.add(Published);
                ar.add(Status);
                ar.add(ThumbUrl);
                ar.add(Title);
                ar.add(id);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(ar));
```

[image: thats the structure I have at firebase.]

How to put that data in an ArrayList? Right now, I'm just able to put all the data at once, but at the end, it only shows the properties of last item in the ArrayList.

Comment: please rephrase your question for it is not clear.

Comment: i want to put all that data shown above in arraylist and i dont know ho to create a new arraylist after the previous one completes with all the tags

Comment: please read up on how to formulate a clear question by SO standards and rewrite your question.  You need to put a tad more effort in formulating your question.

Comment: i've added the code that i'm using rightnow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Arraylist actor=new Arraylist ();
        notification = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        notification1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>;
          actoredata[]={om puri ,raj,};
          directore[]={mahesh bhatt,payrelal};
          for(i=0;i<actoredatalenth(),i++){


            list.put("actor", actore[i])));
        notification.add(list);
            }
            actore.add(notification);
             for(i=0;i<directorelenth(),i++){


            list.put("actor", directore[i])));
        notification.add(list);
            }actore.add(notification);
```

[image]

Comment: use for lopp if you have more data

Comment: like you want to store actor=onpuri,farad masta.

Comment: i want to make an array like (movie) which saves its director, actors or other  subsidiaries so that i could filter out them easily

Comment: ya top array you give movie which store  arralist which has no. of fieald like actore director

Comment: and in inside arralist use hasmap which store only containet data

Comment: user3921943 i m using same consept it is working plz upvote

Comment: see image what i want to tell

Comment: its not what i want, all i want an array which include movie list and every movie contains it's details like actor, director, producer, description